# CSS stripped off when Liferay automatically appends themeId to URL

Tags: css, sass, liferay-6

Liferay automatically appends the themeId (along with other information such as browser) to the URL when including my portlet's css files. When this happens, I find that not all my css styles are loaded. I try to access the css file directly, using **/test-portlet/css/main.css?*themeId=classic***, and only some of the styles are loaded. When I use **/test-portlet/css/main.css** without the themeId appended, all the styles are loaded fine.

I have been unsuccessful in finding out why. Can anyone help me with this? I am using Liferay 6.1.1 (6.1 GA2).

Answer (score 0):

Angeline can you tell me where you are including your /test-portlet/css/main.css ?

This main.css file has your custom css specific to your portlet. So to load your css when the portlet is accessed on Page. You need to **either include in jsp** or the **recommended way** that is to include below line in your test-portlet **liferay-portlet.xml**

```
<header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
```

This will load your css changes.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi Ankit, I have added the main.css file in the liferay-portlet.xml, the same as what you have shown in your code snippet. The inclusion of the css files in the page are automatically done by liferay, but with the additional parameters appended to it.

Comment: Check through firebug the css you have mentioned in your Main.css is loaded for your portlet ?  i.e. when you select your particular html component in your Portlet using firebug, on right side panel it should display css that is getting applied for that html component if your changes does not appear on the applied css list it means something is wrong.. theme css is loaded first, then your portlet mentioned css, then your inline css having the highest preferences.

Comment: Where are seeing this additional parameter getting appended in browser page URL ? what action are you performing that is causing the parameter to be appended ? or while accessing a page having your portlet does it have that parameter automatically ?

Comment: Hi Ankit, the parameter is appended automatically. You can check this by looking at the source for liferay.com as well. All css files included by liferay have the browserId, themeId, minifierType, languageId, timestamp etc appended. It's normally not an issue, but for this case some of my selectors are not loaded.

Comment: Ohh I see you were viewing it on generated page source.. But that will not help debug our problem.. Can you use firebug and see whether your css is getting loaded ? and what is overriding it ? See the second comment I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to rename your css (do not use *main.css*) and it should work.